# CTP5 Invalid column name [Name]_Id for all Fk s while trying to map an existing Database

Tags: orm, mapping, entity-framework-5

I Try This:

```
 Property(c => c.CompanyKindId).HasColumnName("CMPCompanyKindId").HasColumnType("smallint").IsOptional();
 HasOptional(c => c.CompanyKind).WithMany().HasForeignKey(c => c.CompanyKindId);
```

Or This:

```
HasOptional(c => c.CompanyKind).WithMany().Map(m => m.MapKey("CompanyKindId"));
```

In tests I can get list of all types which have no relationship , but all types with relationships (wrote the relation's mapping code above), I get some error like this:

```
 Invalid column name 'CompanyKind_ID' ...
```

Im using vs 2012 , sql server 2012 and the Db generated from script which gotten from 2008 R2.

***Edit:***
I Ignored Properties in relation and Navigation Properties:

```
Ignore(c => c.CompanyKind);
Ignore(c => c.CompanyKindId);
```

but am still getting the same Error.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka: Added more info.

Comment: Can you show the two entity classes of this relationship?

Comment: @Slauma:Company(Id,Name,Code,CompanyKind),CompanyKind(Id,Name)

Comment: Did you check with a debugger breakpoint if you hit your mapping code? The second mapping (the one with `MapKey`) is correct and it should work.

Comment: @Slauma: Checked that but got the same result.maybe some problems happened during moving the Database from `2008 R2` to `2012` (by getting script from `2008 R2` and run that in `2012` !) what you think?

Comment: I don't think it's a problem of moving to the new DB. The underscore in the invalid column indicates that EF is adding a relationship based on conventions, not on your explicit mapping. Is there another relationship between `Company` and `CompanyKind`? Or do you have a collection property in `CompanyKind` refering to companies?

Comment: @Slauma:No I haven't neither of them.

Comment: Can you show the query that throws this error? Did you try btw to create a fresh new project (console app for instance) with only those to classes and the mapping and test if the error occurs then?

Comment: @Slauma:Yes simply `orm.Companies`

Comment: @Slauma:I`m querying in a `Test App` and the error occur even when I query a single table,I get the error for all tables which contain `Foreign Keys`.

Comment: Can you paste the following things into your question: 1) The classes `Company` and `CompanyKind` with *all* properties and data annotation attributes (if you have any), 2) The `OnModelCreating` method of your `DbContext`